# How to add title on line numbers?

Tags: enumerate, line-numbering, lineno

[image]

So I am using the function `\linenumbers` which by default puts a number for each line at the left for the written text. But I somehow need a unit/title on the number but I can't find anything about this?

Example:

```
title
1       Something something
2       Something something
3       Something something
4       Something something
5       Something something
```

I hope someone can lead me in a direction to this!

Comment: How is this related to bibtex?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...Sorry to say that from your post not able to understand your requirement exactly, can you post a `MWE`or an image with clear show???

Comment: Yes i have posted a picture, so i want to make a title like on the picture that i can call Linenumber: or so, and then the number is from the function called \linenumbers.

Comment: Are you looking to add a title in an ``enumerate`` environment? It would be really useful if you provided a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) showing what you already did, and what is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a title and shift it to the left by removing paragraph indent with `\noindent` and shifting it further into the margin by a negative `\hskip` (horizontal skip).

However, line numbers are not really suitable to be used for numbered lists. Firstly, the numbers are in the margin, so they are not really part of the text visually. Secondly, the numbers are for lines, so if you have an item that is more than one line then it is not numbered correctly. Thirdly, the numbers are small, which may not look good if your list items are in a larger font.

The normal environment for numbered list is `enumerate`. You can customize such lists using the `enumitem` package, which allows you to set the indentation, label width, distance between lines, etc.

An example of both the `linenumbers` approach and the `enumerate` approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\noindent \hskip-15pt Title

\linenumbers
Something something

Something something

Something something

Something something

Something something

\nolinenumbers

\vspace{5mm}

\noindent Title
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=-1mm,labelsep=6mm]
\item Something something
\item Something something
\item Something something
\item Something something
\item Something something
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx alot verry helpfull it is now done!